# Wireless driver problem

Tags: wireless, drivers

Can't get my DLINK Wireless usb to work (works on windows). Can anyone help me out, please?

```
lsusb:

ID 0cf3:7015 Atheros Communications, Inc. TP-Link TL-WN821N v3 802.11n [Atheros AR7010+AR9287]
```

Comment: Atheros Communications, Inc. TP-Link TL-WN821N v3 802.11n [Atheros AR7010+AR9287]

That's the USB.

Answer (score 1):

Your device uses the driver ath9k_htc included in all recent Ubuntu versions. It requires firmware that is included in linux-firmware and is installed by default. Let's see if we can load the driver and look for clues as to why it isn't working:

```
sudo modprobe ath9k_htc
dmesg | grep ath
lsb_release -d
rfkill list all
```

Please post the result here: http://paste.ubuntu.com and give us the link in your reply.